# Increase execution time when iOS push notifications arrive

Tags: ios, notifications, background, push, silent

I want to execute some code in the background of an iOS app I’m developing.

I think the best possible way is to trigger the code execution with silent push notifications. However, the time window to do so is limited to 30 seconds. Is it possible to get more time? For example by using [beginbackgroundtask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtask)?

Comment: this is a bad idea. You will drain the battery and people will get angry and remove your App. You should only do work if something really happens. So a notification is a good idea, if it represents an event that is relevant to the user.

Comment: Yes, you can use `beginBackgroundTask` to get up to 3 minutes

Comment: @thomasgotzsche, hopefully the battery drain will keep within limits, because I only plan to trigger the code execution once or twice a day